# NHibernate: One-to-many

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping, one-to-many

I have a class called DadosvalmetSam (Parent) which have a one-to-many relationship with DadosfuncionarioSam(Child).

Classes and mapping below:

DadosvalmetSam

```
public class DadosvalmetSam
{

    public DadosvalmetSam()
    {
        dadosFuncionarios = new List<DadosfuncionarioSam>();
    }

    public virtual int codigoDvm { get; set; }      

    public virtual MetanomeSam codmenDvm { get; set; }      

    public virtual ValidadeSam codvalDvm { get; set; }  

    public virtual IList<DadosfuncionarioSam> dadosFuncionarios { get; set; }

}


public class DadosvalmetSamMap : ClassMap<DadosvalmetSam>
{

    public DadosvalmetSamMap()
    {
        Table("dadosvalmet_sam");
        Id(x => x.codigoDvm).Column("codigo_dvm").GeneratedBy.Identity().Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.codmenDvm).Column("codmen_dvm").Not.Nullable().Not.LazyLoad();
        References(x => x.codvalDvm).Column("codval_dvm").Not.Nullable().Not.LazyLoad();
        HasMany(x => x.dadosFuncionarios).KeyColumn("coddvm_dfu").Cascade.All().Not.LazyLoad();
    }
}
```

DadosfuncionarioSam

```
public class DadosfuncionarioSam
{

    public DadosfuncionarioSam()
    {
    }

    public virtual DadosvalmetSam coddvmDfu { get; set; }       

    public virtual Funcionario codfunDfu { get; set; }      

    public virtual int codigoDfu { get; set; }      

    public virtual float? valorDfu { get; set; }    

}


public class DadosfuncionarioSamMap : ClassMap<DadosfuncionarioSam>
{

    public DadosfuncionarioSamMap()
    {
        Table("dadosfuncionario_sam");
        Id(x => x.codigoDfu).Column("codigo_dfu").GeneratedBy.Identity().Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.codfunDfu).Column("codfun_dfu").Not.Nullable().Not.LazyLoad();
        Map(x => x.valorDfu).Column("valor_dfu").Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.coddvmDfu).Column("coddvm_dfu").Nullable();
    }
}
```

When I'm inserting a DadosvalmetSam, NH inserts all the data inside the IList, that is exactly what I expected. But when I'm Updating a DadosvalmetSam and on this update I removed a row from IList, NH just set the FK in the DadosfuncionarioSam to null and it is not deleting the record, How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
HasMany(x => x.dadosFuncionarios).KeyColumn("coddvm_dfu").Cascade.DeleteOrphans().Not.LazyLoad();
```

Comment: Yes, but this mapping give me an error when building session. MappingException: Unsupported cascade style: delete-orphans